# How to count the total number of coins needed when an input of "amount of change" is entered

Tags: python-3.x

my code is below for the above problem of finding the amount of coins needed for the change entered.

```
# coin values
q = 0.25
d = 0.10
n = 0.05
p = 0.01

# coin counter value
count = 0

change = input("Enter change owed: ")

while True:
    try:
        change = float(change)
        while change <= 0:
            change = float(input("Please re-enter change amount: "))
    except ValueError:
        change = input("Please re-enter the change amount owed: ")
    else:
        break

change = round(change,2)
print(change)


while change > 0:
    if change >= 0.25:
        change = change - q
    elif change >= 0.10:
        change = change - d
    elif change >= 0.05:
        change = change - n
    elif change >= 0.01:
        change = change - p
    else:
        break

    count += 1

print(count)
```

whenever I enter 0.15 it tells me 5 coins but it should be 2. I dont know what the issue is here..please help

Comment: I just figured out by printing after every iteration that float is messing up my change after the first iteration of 0.15 it minuses the dime but then the change value equals .0499999999. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I added another rounder after the iterations...obviously this works but isnt the best way to do it, is there another option I could do without this using float subtraction?

```
   while change > 0:
        if change >= 0.25:
            change = change - q
        elif change >= 0.10:
            change = change - d
        elif change >= 0.05:
            change = change - n
        elif change >= 0.01:
            change = change - p
        else:
            break
    
        change = round(change,2)
        count += 1
    
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the [`decimal` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) to deal with these values as fixed point decimals. Effectively, this would be:

- replacing all the literal `float`s with `Decimal` instances, and
- changing the exception type on invalid input to `InvalidOperation`

So, your code would then look something like:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation

# coin values
q = Decimal('0.25')
d = Decimal('0.10')
n = Decimal('0.05')
p = Decimal('0.01')

# coin counter value
count = 0

change = input("Enter change owed: ")

while True:
    try:
        change = Decimal(change)
        while change <= Decimal('0'):
            change = Decimal(input("Please re-enter change amount: "))
    except InvalidOperation:
        change = Decimal(input("Please re-enter the change amount owed: "))
    else:
        break

change = change.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
print(change)

while change > 0:
    if change >= q:
        change = change - q
    elif change >= d:
        change = change - d
    elif change >= n:
        change = change - n
    elif change >= p:
        change = change - p
    else:
        break

    count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will look at the Decimal library, I appreciate the feedback.